# Is it possible to get location data for EV charging stations by querying the HERE REST-API?

Tags: here-api

Is it possible to get location data for EV charging stations by querying the HERE REST-API?

The seem to offer [something](https://www.here.com/products/automotive/ev-charging-stations) , but I had a look at the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/develop/rest-apis) and could not find out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EV charging stations information is only available for customers with a paid contract(not for freemium users). Please view the documentation here - https://developer.here.com/automotive/documentation