# How can I get access to HERE EV Charge Points API

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to get access to the Here EV Charge Points API. It has already been mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57309160/is-it-possible-to-get-location-data-for-ev-charging-stations-by-querying-the-her/65945706#65945706) that it is not available in the Freemium plan. However I was not able to find helpful information about what plan is needed to get access. Could you please provide me with the information about the required plan and the corresponding costs?

Answer (score 1):

EV Charge Points API is currently not a part of any of our bundle offerings. You can [reach out to the sales team](https://www.here.com/contact) and ask for a usage license. Pro tip: You might be able to also get an evaluation license to try the API before committing to it, so ask them about it.

Comment: I've never seen a website so complicated to understand what exactly they're selling, how much it costs and how to access. The EV Charge Points API is mentioned in the "Dynamic Map Content" page and then there's NO reference in the pricing page. What's the point of this confusion? To force you to contact them?